# How do you get/set the OnClientClick property of an input tag programmatically using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have an asp.net button in my page. i would like to set and retrieve the OnClientClick property of the button using JavaScript, but get *undefined* when i display the property's value using

```
alert(printButton.OnClientClick)
```

i set the printButton object with this code:

```
var printButton = args.get_item().get_cell("TemplateColumnView").getElementsByTagName('input')[0]
```

i know that is code works because i am able to retrieve the id, src etc. properties of printButton but cannot get OnClientClick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OnClientClick` is ASP.NET. The client click event in ASP.NET is the same as the click event in JavaScript.

Using your `printButton` variable, in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari, it would look something like this:

```
printButton.addEventListener(
    'click', 
    function() { 
        /* Handle the click event */ 
    });
```

In IE:

```
printButton.attachEvent(
    'onclick', 
    function() { 
         /* Handle the click event */ 
    });
```

Or with the jQuery framework:

```
$(printButton).click(function() { 
    /* Handle the click event */ 
});
```